# How do I copy an employee information from one dictionary to another?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object, pickle

I am using the Python class Employee to copy create employees in an employee management system and pickle to a file. I got that to work fine, but my instructor wants to be able to search the system even for deleted employees. My question is how do I copy an object from employeDictionary to deletedemployeeDictionary? I keep running into errors.

Here is my employee class:

```
class Employee:
# Initialize Employee object
def __init__(self, name, ID, department, job):
    self.__ID = ID
    self.__name = name
    self.__department = department
    self.__job = job

# Set each object
def set_name(self, name):
    self.__name = name

def set_ID(self, ID):
    self.__ID = ID

def set_dept(self, department):
    self.__department = department

def set_job(self, job):
    self.__job = job

# Get each object
def get_name(self):
    return self.name

def get_ID(self):
    return self.__ID

def get_department(self):
    return self.__department

def get_job(self):
    return self.__job

def __str__(self):
    return (f"ID Number: {self.__ID}\nName: {self.__name}\n"
            f"Department: {self.__department}\n Job Title: {self.__job}")
```

Here is my main code:

```
import pickle
import emp2

def main():
    # Try to open the existing dictionary file
    try:
        inputFile1 = open('employee.pickle', 'rb')
        employeeDictionary = pickle.load(inputFile1)
        inputFile1.close()
        inputFile2 = open('deletedEmployee.pickle', 'rb')
        deletedEmployeeDictionary = pickle.load(inputFile2)
        inputFile2.close()

    except:
        employeeDictionary = {}
        deletedEmployeeDictionary = {}

   # While loop to continue until user chooses to quit
    proceed = True
    while proceed:

        # Display user's option menu and ask for a choice
        print('\n Employee Management System\n')
        print('\t1. Lookup an employee')
        print('\t2. Add a new employee')
        print('\t3. Change an existing employee')
        print('\t4. Delete an existing employee')
        print('\t5. Save and Quit\n')
        
        choice = int(input('Enter an option to continue: '))
        
        if choice == 1:
            lookup (employeeDictionary, deletedEmployeeDictionary)
        elif choice ==2:
            add(employeeDictionary)
        elif choice == 3:
            change (employeeDictionary)
        elif choice == 4:
            delete (employeeDictionary, deletedEmployeeDictionary)
        elif choice == 5:
            save_quit(employeeDictionary, deletedEmployeeDictionary)
            proceed = False
        else:
            print ('Invalid input!')
            choice = int(input('Enter an option to continue: '))

# Lookup an employee
def lookup(dictionary, dictionary2):
    # Look up the ID number if it is in the dictionary
    employee_id = int(input('Enter the employee ID number: '))
    if employee_id in dictionary:
        # print('employee_id', ': ', dictionary[employee_id])
        print(dictionary.get(employee_id))
    elif employee_id in dictionary2:
        # print('employee_id', ': ', dictionary2[employee_id])
        print(dictionary2.get(employee_id))
    else:
        print("That ID number was not found.")


# Add an employee
def add(dictionary):
    # Add a new employee
    empyloyee_id = int(input('Enter the employee ID number: '))
    if empyloyee_id not in dictionary.keys():
        name = input('Enter the name of the employee: ')
        dept = input('Enter the employee department: ')
        job = input('Enter the employee job title: ')
        entry = emp2.Employee(name, empyloyee_id, dept, job)
        dictionary[empyloyee_id] = entry
        print('Employee added succesfully')
    else:
        print('Employee already exists!')

# Change an employee
def change(dictionary):
    # If user-entered ID is in dictionary, allow them to change the info
    employee_id = int(input(
        'Enter the employee ID you would like to change: '))
    if employee_id in dictionary.keys():
        name = input('Enter new employee name: ')
        dept = input('Enter new employee department: ')
        job = input('Enter new employee job title: ')
        entry = emp2.Employee(name, employee_id, dept, job)
        dictionary[employee_id] = entry
        print('Employee changed successfully.')
    else:
        print('That employee ID was not found.')

# Delete an employee
def delete(dictionary, dictionary2):
    # If user-entered ID is in dictionary, delete the entry
    employee_id = int(input(
        'Enter the employee ID you would like to remove: '))
    if employee_id in dictionary.keys():
        entry = emp2.Employee(dictionary[employee_id])
        dictionary2[empyloyee_id] = entry
        del dictionary[employee_id]
        print('Employee successfully moved to deleted directory!')
    else:
        print('That employee ID was not found.')



# Save the dictionary and quit the program
def save_quit(dictionary, dictionary2):
    # Pickle the dictionary and save to a file
    outputFile1 = open('employee.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(dictionary, outputFile1)
    outputFile1.close
    # Pickle the dictionary and save to a file
    outputFile2 = open('deletedEmployee.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(dictionary2, outputFile2)
    outputFile2.close

def move(dictionary, dictionary2, employee_id):
    empyloyee_id = dictionary.get(employee_id)
    name = dictionary.get(name)
    dept = dictionary.get(department)
    job = dictionary.get(job)
    
    entry = emp2.Employee(name, empyloyee_id, dept, job)
    dictionary2[empyloyee_id] = entry
    
#Calls main function.   
if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What kind of errors? Be more specific. Include traceback from error in your post. Do you want people to read through your entire code and guess where an error might be coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You have several pieces that require update.

1. In your lookup function, you do not inform the user whether or not the employee is in the active list or deleted list.  You might want to let them know.
2. I moved your MOVE function to above the delete function.  since your DELETE function requires a move call, having MOVE above DELETE gives the ability to handle the function once.
3. In your DELETE, we updated the script to allow for MOVE to happen, then we can use the POP function to remove the object from the roster.

```
import pickle
import employee as emp2


def main():
    # Try to open the existing dictionary file
    try:
        inputFile1 = open('employee.pickle', 'rb')
        employeeDictionary = pickle.load(inputFile1)
        inputFile1.close()
        inputFile2 = open('deletedEmployee.pickle', 'rb')
        deletedEmployeeDictionary = pickle.load(inputFile2)
        inputFile2.close()

    except:
        employeeDictionary = {}
        deletedEmployeeDictionary = {}

    # While loop to continue until user chooses to quit
    proceed = True
    while proceed:

        # Display user's option menu and ask for a choice
        print('\n Employee Management System\n')
        print('\t1. Lookup an employee')
        print('\t2. Add a new employee')
        print('\t3. Change an existing employee')
        print('\t4. Delete an existing employee')
        print('\t5. Save and Quit\n')

        choice = int(input('Enter an option to continue: '))

        if choice == 1:
            lookup(employeeDictionary, deletedEmployeeDictionary)
        elif choice == 2:
            add(employeeDictionary)
        elif choice == 3:
            change(employeeDictionary)
        elif choice == 4:
            delete(employeeDictionary, deletedEmployeeDictionary)
        elif choice == 5:
            save_quit(employeeDictionary, deletedEmployeeDictionary)
            proceed = False
        else:
            print('Invalid input!')
            choice = int(input('Enter an option to continue: '))


# Lookup an employee
def lookup(dictionary, dictionary2):
    # Look up the ID number if it is in the dictionary
    employee_id = int(input('Enter the employee ID number: '))
    if employee_id in dictionary:
        # print('employee_id', ': ', dictionary[employee_id])
        print('Active Record...')
        print(dictionary.get(employee_id))
    elif employee_id in dictionary2:
        # print('employee_id', ': ', dictionary2[employee_id])
        print("Deleted Record...")
        print(dictionary2.get(employee_id))
    else:
        print("That ID number was not found.")


# Add an employee
def add(dictionary):
    # Add a new employee
    empyloyee_id = int(input('Enter the employee ID number: '))
    if empyloyee_id not in dictionary.keys():
        name = input('Enter the name of the employee: ')
        dept = input('Enter the employee department: ')
        job = input('Enter the employee job title: ')
        entry = emp2.Employee(name, empyloyee_id, dept, job)
        dictionary[empyloyee_id] = entry
        print('Employee added succesfully')
    else:
        print('Employee already exists!')


# Change an employee
def change(dictionary):
    # If user-entered ID is in dictionary, allow them to change the info
    employee_id = int(input(
        'Enter the employee ID you would like to change: '))
    if employee_id in dictionary.keys():
        name = input('Enter new employee name: ')
        dept = input('Enter new employee department: ')
        job = input('Enter new employee job title: ')
        entry = emp2.Employee(name, employee_id, dept, job)
        dictionary[employee_id] = entry
        print('Employee changed successfully.')
    else:
        print('That employee ID was not found.')

def move(dictionary, dictionary2, employee_id):
    dictionary2[employee_id] = dictionary.get(employee_id)

# Delete an employee
def delete(dictionary, dictionary2):
    # If user-entered ID is in dictionary, delete the entry
    employee_id = int(input(
        'Enter the employee ID you would like to remove: '))
    if employee_Id in dictionary:
         move(dictionary, dictionary2, employee_id)
         dictionary.pop(employee_id)
         print('Employee successfully moved to deleted directory!')
    else:
         print('Employee not in directory!')

# Save the dictionary and quit the program
def save_quit(dictionary, dictionary2):
    # Pickle the dictionary and save to a file
    outputFile1 = open('employee.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(dictionary, outputFile1)
    outputFile1.close
    # Pickle the dictionary and save to a file
    outputFile2 = open('deletedEmployee.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(dictionary2, outputFile2)
    outputFile2.close





# Calls main function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I will take your advice on informing the user. I never really thought about the order to put functions in, but thanks I will remember that. Again, thanks for the help.